# org.apache.commons.net.ftp use different port

Tags: java, apache, servlets, ftp, ftp-client

I want to connect to a FTP-Server via my Servlet and I know it works, but to use it on my virtual Server I need to change the Port the servlet connects to, because the FTP-Server doesn't use the standard port.

My problem is, that I don't know how I can tell the FTPClient not to use Port 21. For example it should use Port "55555".

The FTPClient only wants one parameter, the ip, to connect.

```
using org.apache.commons.net.ftp 
FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();
ftp.connect("dyndns");
```

best SnowN

Answer (score 16, accepted):

you should use method connect(host,port)

Comment: You are right. I was seriously sure that this command doesn`t exists. I've also previously looked and searched, but yet it seems I was completely blind. I'm sorry for this stupid question. Nevertheless many thanks for the quick and nice help.

Comment: you're not blind neither it's a stupid question. The problem is that the javadoc was poorly generated (http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html) this method is way above in the class hierarchy (http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/SocketClient.html).